# How to add a few properties at UITableViewCell class?

Tags: class, properties

I'm using UITableViewController and UINavigationController.
I would like to save some information on tableViewCell.

UITableViewCell_extensionOf.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

@interface UITableViewCell ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *onDate;

@end

MasterViewController.m file

#import "UITableViewCell_extensionOf.h"

......

-(void)viewDidLoad {

.....
   UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];

**cell.onDate = [NSDate date];**     //crash

}

error log : -[UIAccessibilityBundle setOnDate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7381b90

How can I add some extra properties at the UITableViewCell? My last card is subclass, is it only way to get this work? (actually, I haven't tried subclass yet)